# Python async function running synchronously?

Tags: python, tkinter, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am working on a Tkinter GUI for a text to speech project and for the voice conversion feature I want to record and play audio. My problem is that this stalls the GUI so I am trying to run this code asynchronously.

when using this function to play a .wav file and running it using asyncio the GUI still stalls then it reaches the while loop. If I replace the while loop with 'await asyncio.sleep(5)' the program doesn't stall so the function is definitely asynchronous but the loop is posing an issue.

```
async def PlayPreview():
    global previewBar
    soundName = dropLangs.get() + "-" + dropSpeakers.get() + "-" + dropModels.get() + ".wav"
    soundPath = "./tts_models/" + dropLangs.get() + "/" + dropSpeakers.get() + "/" + dropModels.get() + "/" + soundName
    #previewSound = wave(soundPath)
    chunk = 1024
    waveFile = wave.open(soundPath, 'rb')
    port = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = port.open(format = port.get_format_from_width(waveFile.getsampwidth()),
                channels = waveFile.getnchannels(),
                rate = waveFile.getframerate(),
                output = True)
    data = waveFile.readframes(chunk)
    st = stream.get_time()
    frames = waveFile.getnframes()
    rate = waveFile.getframerate()
    length = frames/float(rate)
    while len(data := waveFile.readframes(chunk)):
        stream.write(data)
    stream.close()
    port.terminate()
    print("done")
```

I have tried separating thew while loop into it's own async function and just awaiting it in the PlayPreview() function but that didn't make a difference.

FYI: the PlayPreview() function is called using the async-tkinter-loop package (modified to work with the customtkinter package) which essentially creates an asyncio task for it.

Comment: You can't solve this with async.  All async routines still share a single thread, so they're going to block the UI.  You would need to use a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use asyncio to wait for all other processes to run.
Here is an updated version of your script:

```
import wave
import pyaudio
import asyncio
import threading

def play_audio():
    soundName = dropLangs.get() + "-" + dropSpeakers.get() + "-" + dropModels.get() + ".wav"
    soundPath = "./tts_models/" + dropLangs.get() + "/" + dropSpeakers.get() + "/" + dropModels.get() + "/" + soundName

    chunk = 1024
    waveFile = wave.open(soundPath, 'rb')
    port = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = port.open(format=port.get_format_from_width(waveFile.getsampwidth()),
                       channels=waveFile.getnchannels(),
                       rate=waveFile.getframerate(),
                       output=True)

    data = waveFile.readframes(chunk)
    while len(data) > 0:
        stream.write(data)
        data = waveFile.readframes(chunk)

    stream.close()
    port.terminate()
    print("done")

async def play_audio_async():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, play_audio)

async def PlayPreview():
    await play_audio_async()
    print("Playback completed")

# Call PlayPreview() to start the audio playback

# Example usage with async-tkinter-loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(PlayPreview())
```

Don't forget to make sure you have the modules downloaded.

Comment: This is STILL going to block the UI while this runs.  You cannot solve that problem with `async`, because ALL `async` routines still share a single thread.  The only way to keep the UI responsive is to use threads.

Comment: Actually @TimRoberts this solution works great because I the run_in_executor function puts the operation into a separate thread

Answer (score 1):

Python's `async` functions are "cooperative". That means the execution is only handed to another function at specific places, namely the `await`ed calls. This is in contrast to threads, where the execution can be preempted at any point.

Your problem is that the `while` loop never hands over execution, so the other tasks never have a chance to run. And that's why the five second sleep worked.

To manually yield the execution, include a zero-seconds sleep inside the loop:

```py
while len(data := waveFile.readframes(chunk)):
    stream.write(data)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

But this is a hacky solution. Ideally, you would use a `readframes` function that is itself async.

Comment: thanks this works but you are right it is a bit hacky so i think ill go with the solution bellow but thank you for your help